# Getting the data used by a Chart in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-sheets-api

I want to read the charts created on a google spreadsheet and recreate them using google charts on my website.

I can use the google spreadsheet api and get a response from `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/#{spreadsheet_id}`

The response include `sheets` containing all the sheet data, and the sheet data contains 'charts' data related to the charts in the sheet.

Now, I want to get the data used by the charts. Under the sources in the ChartSpec all the data is in this format:

```
{
   "sheetId": number,
   "startRowIndex": number,
   "endRowIndex": number,
   "startColumnIndex": number,
   "endColumnIndex": number,
}
```

Consult [this](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#gridrange) for more information on GridRange.
I can get the cells used by the chart to plot the data. But `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/#{spreadsheet_id}/values/#{range}` only accepts a range in A1 notation.

I do have written a function that converts the GridRange to A1 but is there an easier way to get the data a spreadsheet chart uses?

Thanks

PS: I am using ruby to do this. My website is built on Ruby on Rails.

Comment: At Sheets API v4, a1Notation is mainly used. If you want to use GridRange, how about the use of Web Apps? Web Apps can be created by GAS. When the ruby side requests to Web Apps using a url query, Web Apps returns the data you want. In this case, at the ruby side, the data can be retrieved using the request with GET method. If this was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: But I'll have to still use the A1 notation.